# Domain Driven Development: Detecting changes (.NET)

Tags: domain-driven-design, data-access-layer

I've just started with Domain Driven Design and trying to apply it for my current project.

I've started with a pure domain model and now stuck with my Data Access layer. I have a completely home made data access layer therefore no any of well known ORM tools can be applied here.

I cannot figure out how to deal with updates. Let's say I have the following Objects:

```
public class Document : Entity
{
    public IPropertiesCollection Properties { get; set; }

    public IContents Contents { get; set; }
}

public class PostalDocumentsPackage : Entity
{
    public String Name { get; set; }

    public DateTime DeliverDate { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Document> Documents { get; set; } 
}
```

I have corresponding repositories IDocumentsRepository and IPostalDocumentPackagesRepository for retrieving objects (for now).

The problem I deal with now is to situation when i want to add a new document do Documents collection of PostalDocumentsPackage. Basically I see two possible cases here:

1) Implement the collection that track changes in original collection and holds lists of items that were updated\removed.

2) Implement separate methods in repository for adding documents to the package.

I wonder are these approaches is ok or can cause problems in future? or there is another alternatives?

Comment: Boy oh boy, I'm afraid you have a lot of work cut out for you. Sprinkling entity and repository in a model does not make it DDD. Instead of tracking the document, track the document identifiers. Also, since you're using custom persistence, try to encapsulate state a bit more. Think about the behavior of an object first, state will follow naturaly, I promise.

Comment: To quote Jeff Atwood: "Don't Reinvent The Wheel, Unless You Plan on Learning More About Wheels". So, are you learning about ORMs? If not, why are you reinventing an ORM?

Answer (score 0):

Typically change tracking would be handled by an ORM such as NHibernate. In your case you may be able to do the following:

- Select new documents based on the value of the identity property.
- Issue a SQL delete statement before re-inserting into the table.

A problem with either approach is that the documents collection may be big, such that loading all documents for each `PostalDocumentsPackage` may be a bottleneck. Also you must consider whether you need change tracking on the `Document` entity in addition to the documents collection. If so, then you would need to implement change tracking for the `Document` class as well. Given that you're not using an ORM I would suggest solution #2 since solution #1 will  lead you down a path of re-implementing change tracking, which among other things would pollute your domain classes. You may also consider a [CQRS/Event Sourcing](http://codebetter.com/gregyoung/2010/02/13/cqrs-and-event-sourcing/) architecture in which change tracking is made explicit.